# Does the Sneak Attack class feature of the Generic Classes stack with the improved and greater versions of it?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, sneak-attack

[Generic Classes](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/genericClasses.htm) have the possibility to gain different class features in exchange of a bonus feat:

> For the purposes of these classes, the following class features can be selected in place of bonus feats (unless noted, each may only be selected once).

The Sneak Attack class features that can be selected are:

> **Sneak Attack (Ex)**
>
> As the rogue ability, but +2d6 on damage rolls.
> *Prerequisites*: Hide 4 ranks, Move Silently 4 ranks.
>
> **Improved Sneak Attack (Ex)**
>
> Add +3d6 to your sneak attack damage.
> *Prerequisites*: Hide 11 ranks, Move Silently 11 ranks, sneak attack.
>
> **Greater Sneak Attack (Ex)**
>
> Add +4d6 to your sneak attack damage.
> *Prerequisites*: Hide 18 ranks, Move Silently 18 ranks, sneak attack,
> improved sneak attack.

Do these three class features stack together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

It's not explicitly stated on the handbook, but the generic sneak attack class feature is supposed to be similar to the rogue ability. With them you would have +2d6 at level 1, +5d6 at level 8, and +9d6 at level 15, if you take them as soon as possible. You get more damage earlier than the rogue (which would get +2d6 at lvl 3, +5d6 at lvl 9, and +9d6 at lvl 17), but the rogue can't exist at the same time as generic classes, so it's fine.

Comment: It is actually stated. It says to add the extra dice, so you do. The only thing that isn't stated is that you shouldn't treat them like they don't stack.

Comment: @J.Mini It does says, "As the rogue's ability," and that stacks.

Comment: You're correct, I just said it isn't an **explicit** statement.